# How can I show a list of *all* available calendars using Google Calendar API v3 / Google API Client Library?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-client

I have been trying to access the Google Calendar API v3 using PHP. Initially, I want to simply list the user calendars that are accessible to my call to the API.

To do so, I have downloaded the Google API PHP Client Library and have attempted to use the following code (which is sourced, with my adaptations, from https://mytechscraps.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/accessing-google-calendar-using-the-php-api/ ):

```
<?php

//error_reporting(0);
//@ini_set('display_errors', 0);

// If you've used composer to include the library, remove the following line
// and make sure to follow the standard composer autoloading.
// https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading
require_once './google-api-php-client-master/autoload.php';

// Service Account info
$client_id = '754612121864-pmdfssdfakqiqblg6lt9a.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$service_account_name = '754674507864-pm1dsgdsgsdfsdfsdfdflg6lt9a@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = 'Calendar-7dsfsdgsdfsda953d68dgdsgdsff88a.p12';


$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Calendar");

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
 $service_account_name,
 array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'),
 $key
);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

$cals = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
print_r($cals);

?>
```

I have created a service account in the Google Developers console, and generated OAuth details, which I have used to set the appropriate variables as can be seen from the code.

This code returns the following:

```
Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarList Object ( [collection_key:protected] => items [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array ( ) [etag] => "14171313334000" [itemsType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry [itemsDataType:protected] => array [kind] => calendar#calendarList [nextPageToken] => [nextSyncToken] => 000014121268327000 [modelData:protected] => Array ( [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [kind] => calendar#calendarListEntry [etag] => "1417721316542000" [id] => bots@madeupcompany.co.uk [summary] => bots@madeupcompany.co.uk [timeZone] => Europe/London [colorId] => 23 [backgroundColor] => #cd74e6 [foregroundColor] => #000000 [selected] => 1 [accessRole] => reader [defaultReminders] => Array ( ) ) ) ) [processed:protected] => Array ( ) )
```

The problem is that this seems to be returning details of only *one* calendar. That is, the calendar for bots@madeupcompany.co.uk (the only one I explicitly shared with my service).

However, I know this google account has read-only access to a number of other user's calendars (I can see them when logged into Google Calendar as this user).

Furthermore, if I use the Google Apps Explorer on this page: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list#auth , while logged into my google account as bots@madeupcompany.co.uk, I get details of *all* of these other calendars.

So I'm trying to work out, why is the Apps Explorer showing me all the other calendars, and yet the PHP code is not?

Comment: Have you tried to add calendars through Calendar services itself and check if those are being listed ?

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert

Answer (score 1):

A service account doesn’t need to prompt a user for access because you have to set it up. Go to the Google Calendar  website.  Find the Calendar Settings , then go to the Calendars tab,  find the calendar you want to access and click on  “Shared: Edit settings”  add the service account email address like you would a persons email address.      This will give the service account the same access as if you where sharing it with any other user.

```
<?php
session_start();        
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Calendar.php';     
/************************************************   
 The following 3 values an befound in the setting   
 for the application you created on Google      
 Developers console.         Developers console.
 The Key file should be placed in a location     
 that is not accessable from the web. outside of 
 web root.   

 In order to access your GA account you must    
 Add the Email address as a user at the     
 ACCOUNT Level in the GA admin.         
 ************************************************/
$client_id = '1046123799103-nk421gjc2v8mlr2qnmmqaak04ntb1dbp.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$Email_address = '1046123799103-nk421gjc2v8mlr2qnmmqaak04ntb1dbp@developer.gserviceaccount.com';     
$key_file_location = '629751513db09cd21a941399389f33e5abd633c9-privatekey.p12';     
$client = new Google_Client();      
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);    
// seproate additional scopes with a comma   
$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";   
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(    
    $Email_address,      
    array($scopes),     
    $key         
    );      
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {        
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);       
}       
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);    

?>

<html><body>

<?php
$calendarList  = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
print_r($calendarList);
while(true) {
    foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
        echo "<a href='Oauth2.php?type=event&id=".$calendarListEntry->id." '>".$calendarListEntry->getSummary()."</a><br>\n";
    }
    $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
    if ($pageToken) {
        $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
        $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}    

?>
</html>
```

code ripped from tutorial [Google Calendar API with PHP – Service Account](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account/)